# What protects my Facebook application from being impersonated?

Tags: javascript, facebook, security, facebook-javascript-sdk

Facebook [JavaScript SDK guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) contains an example code to integrate Facebook login and authorization for a specific application. The only information provided to this script is the App ID.

Let's say an user authorizes my application to access his private data. Now, what prevents someone else to put a Facebook login form on his *own* application using *my* App ID and JavaScript to make it look like it came from my domain and access this user's private data?

Do browsers provide enough security on this subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, what prevents someone else to put a Facebook login form on his own application using my App ID and JavaScript to make it look like it came from my domain and access this user's private data?
>
> Do browsers provide enough security on this subject?

Nothing to do with the browser, really. Facebook will only pass data back to a domain that's in your whitelisted set of app domains in the [developer console](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/).

[image]

Comment: How can the Facebook API make sure it is communicating with a page on a whitelisted domain? Doesn't it has to rely on browser informations at some point?

Comment: @Yovar Sure, but if the user's browser is compromised by malware that's attacking your Facebook integration their access tokens are already long gone.

Comment: It depends on where and how the domain informations are retrieved. I apologize for not being explicit enough, my question is rather: Technically, what domain safety mechanisms are in play and what makes them secure with a website executing hostile JavaScript on a non-compromised browser?

Answer (score 1):

When the SDK redirects user to Facebook, Facebook's servers redirects back to your site. The redirect URL is set by you in the App Settings of Facebook Developer Center. If someone steals your App Id and puts it in his site, all of his users would be redirected to your site.